# Clear the Cache in Android Webview

Tags: android, webview, browser-cache

I have Webview in my Android app, In Webview there are two buttons pre and next , I want to clear the Webview cache on button Click...

I have been trying to figure out the way to clear the cache, So please help!!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041205/android-webview-clear-cache

Answer (score 1):

To clear cache you use :
[clearCache()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#clearCache(boolean))

> But Note :This will clear the cache for all WebViews used.

[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465432/android-webview-completely-clear-the-cache)